# Cant get data from Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, viewmodel

I have a problem with getting data from `check_list_table`. `insert` method executes normally and there is no error or warning, but `allItems` property doesn't work.

Item, ItemDao and ViewModel class are shown below:

```
@Entity(tableName = "check_list_table")
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var title: String,
    var priority: Int=0
)
```

```
interface ItemDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(item: Item)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(item: Item)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM check_list_table ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getAllItems():LiveData<List<Item>>

}
```

```
class DailyCheckListItemViewModel(private val itemDao: ItemDao, application: Application) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val viewModelJob = Job()
    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

    val allItems = itemDao.getAllItems().value


    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
    }

    fun onAdd(item: Item) {
        uiScope.launch {
            insertItem(item)
        }
    }

    suspend fun insertItem(item: Item) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            itemDao.insert(item)
        }
    }

}
```

- `insert` method called.
- `insert` method called with a proper feed.
- `insert` method is called from a non-ui thread

Comment: Where does `ItemDao` come from? How are you "checking the database" to see that it's empty?

Comment: ItemDao comes from ViewModelFactory and I checked database table using device file explorer in android studio and Log on allItems [property in ViewModel class].

Comment: Change `insert` to return a `Long` which should give you the ID of the item inserted and see what you get. Also try the [Database Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database) and see if that gives any clues.

Comment: Opps. I checked database using DB Browser and insert was done but Why I cant getData from database [using allItems Property]? allItems.value.toString() returns "null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I cant getData from database [using allItems Property]?

You've defined an observable read operation:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM check_list_table ORDER BY id DESC")
fun getAllItems():LiveData<List<Item>>
```

But are reading it in a direct manner:

```
val allItems = itemDao.getAllItems().value
```

This will not work because the `LiveData` object must be observed to actually trigger the database read.

You can either ...

**Make the read operation a "one-shot" (non-observable) operation (if you only need to read the data once)**

Change the `DAO` to just return a list of items, not a `LiveData`:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM check_list_table ORDER BY id DESC")
suspend fun getAllItems():List<Item>
```

And change the `ViewModel` to fetch that data all at once:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){ allItems = itemDao.getAllItems() }
```

**Or make the `ViewModel` variable a `LiveData` as well and observe it in the UI (if the data can change and you want to refresh the UI as it does)**

The `DAO` stays the same:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM check_list_table ORDER BY id DESC")
fun getAllItems():LiveData<List<Item>>
```

The ViewModel just references the `LiveData`:

```
val allItems = itemDao.getAllItems()
```

And your `Activity`/`Fragment` observes the changes. Now that the `LiveData` is being observed, the read operation will be triggered and the data returned:

```
viewModel.allItems.observe(/*lifecycle*/) { items ->
    // Do something with the list of items that was read
}
```